# Design bash script for extract unknown file name section

Tags: bash

I have to make a simple design but i don't know how to do it

I have two folders folderA and folder B. Inside of folderA I have two files named "file_" and "file_anything". The "anything" part of the second file is some text i don't know (or that can be different for various folders). What i need to do is change the name of folderB to whatever text is "anything" without needing to know specifically

I would aprreciate if beyond the procedure someone gives me a link to the topics taht you have use to understand and be able to modify or adapt the solutuions to others situations. I want to learn

thanks

edit:
i need this solution to be included inside a bash script (no perl functions) that is gonna be repeated for a lot of couples of folders that have the same estructure. For example:

FolderA (with files "file_" and "file_manana") and FolderB--- change to---> FolderA and manana (former FolderB)

FolderC (with files "file_" and "file_monkey") and FolderD--- change to ---> FolderA and monkey (former FolderD)

FolderE (with files "file_" and "file_moose") and FolderF--- change to ---> FolderA and moose (former FolderF)

many many times with many more folders

Edit 2:

Ok, i'm getting closer. the problem now is this: I define fn like this: fn=file_a* knowing that in that folder is only one file that matches that indictation. I confirm this doing echo $fn. Now i do this: fn=${fn##*_}. However, fn don't tranform into "anything" but into "a*". What do i fix that? @David Zaslavsky

Edit 3: Thx @chepner . BASH_REMATCH was the way to go. I use it with a little change because the way you wrote it didin't work for me

```
for f in FolderA/file_*; do # I assume a single match
[[ $f =~ "file_"(.*) ]]
suffix=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
mv FolderB "$suffix"
done
```

Note the quotation marks. Between them I can even include spaces

Thx everyone

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you question, but I think `rename` cmd can help you. You only give an `ed` command for rename files. Ex: `s/file_//` for delete this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what your end result should be, but you can extract the trailing part of `file_anything` with the following:

```
$ f="file_manana"
$ [[ $f =~ file_(.*) ]]
$ suffix=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
$ echo $suffix
manana
```

So what I think you want to do is

```
for f in FolderA/file_*; do # I assume a single match
    [[ $f =~ file_(.*) ]]
    suffix=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    mv FolderB "$suffix"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look up parameter expansion in the [Bash manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash). If you store the name of `file_anything` in a variable, let's say `fn`, you can use `${fn##*_}` to remove the longest prefix matching `*_` from the filename, and then you can use that in a `mv` command to rename folder B.

Comment: Ok, i'm getting closer. the problem now is this:  I define fn like this: fn=file_a* knowing that in that carpet is only one file that matches that indictation. I confirm this doing echo $fn. Now i do this: fn=${fn##*_}. However, fn don't tranform into "anything" but into "a*". What do i fix that? @David Zaslavsky

Comment: please don't try to refine your problem definition in the comments section. Edit your question to include formatted sample input, and required output from that input. Good luck.

Comment: @user1620160 what shellter said. Your comment is asking about something different; there were no wildcards in the original question. It may help if you can supply a few actual filenames.

Comment: That is true. But I'm using wildcards because (as I refers in the original post) i dont know what exact name has the file after underscore. Also, I'm using it to be able to aplicate the indication by @DavidZaslavsky